# css - absolute positioning with orientation changes on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, mobile

I have a mobile website I am building and I want a logo positioned at the bottom of the screen. It displays properly in either landscape and portrait mode when initially loaded, but on orientation change between the two, the position doesn't update itself to the proper location. How do I accomplish this? Here's my css:

```
#logo { position:absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
```

I have access to javascript / jquery to position it if necessary, but I would prefer to find a purely css based solution. I am already using media queries - but the overall window height doesn't seem to be adjusting properly in iphone. Works fine in android.

Comment: [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) might help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">

/* Portrait */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
    #logo {right: 10px; }

}

/* Landscape */

@media screen and (min-width: 321px)
{
    #logo {right: ___}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm using media queries actually, but in iPhone it is not positioning them properly. Regardless of orientation, I want it 10px from the bottom and right, but iPhone loses track of where the bottom is somehow on orientation change.